# Can I substitute dependencies for a module (for example, replace node-fetch with the inbuilt fetch) using Vite?

Tags: fetch, vite, node-fetch

I have a number of packages that depend on `node-fetch`:

```
$ npm ls node-fetch
myapp@1.0.0 /home/mike/Code/myapp@1.0.0 
├─┬ @metaplex-foundation/js@0.18.1
│ ├─┬ @bundlr-network/client@0.8.9
│ │ └─┬ near-api-js@0.44.2
│ │   └── node-fetch@2.6.7 deduped
│ └── node-fetch@2.6.7
├─┬ @solana/spl-token-registry@0.2.7
│ └─┬ cross-fetch@3.1.5
│   └── node-fetch@2.6.7 deduped
└─┬ @solana/web3.js@1.73.2
  └── node-fetch@2.6.7 deduped
```

Fetch is now part of Node 18, and recent versions remove the warning about it being experimental.

Is it possible to replace any imports of `node-fetch` to just use Node's `global.fetch`?

I imagining something like a Vite build option, but I don't know what to search for. I've already looked at the [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html) and since Vite uses Rollup the [Rollup docs](https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/).

Reading https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias I can see there are aliases from a package to another package,
I just have to work out if/how I make this use a global instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. This is called an `alias` in Vite.

There doesn't seem to be a way to replace an NPM module with an inbuilt object, but I wrote [a small NPM module that exposes the inbuilt `globalThis.fetch` as a default export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/just-use-native-fetch). This can be used as a `node-fetch` substitute:

`npm i just-use-native-fetch`

Then [add an alias in your Vite config](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#resolve-alias):

```
export default defineConfig({
  ...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "node-fetch": "just-use-native-fetch",
    },
  },
  ...
}
```